# Installing Mingw-w64 without admin rights

Tags: gcc, mingw, mingw64

How can I install [Mingw-w64](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) without admin rights?

Note that I was able to install [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) without admin rights.

I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the 7z file from : `https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/`

If you intend to install the windows version, click the `x86_64-posix-seh` from `MinGW-W64 GCC-8.1.0`, and just uncompress the 7z file.

Answer (score 1):

This is up to the developer of mingw-w64.

Local admin is required to make applications available to all users, or to write information to protected areas of the system.

If the developer supports installing as non-admin users then it should be an option and the support documentation should contain this information or the developer could provide it. If the application does not yet support installing without admin rights, only the developer can change that.

Comment: In your scenario I am the developer. In general, how does one install [Mingw-w64](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) without admin rights?

Comment: Like I said, ask the developer.

Comment: I am the developer and I don't know how! To clarify, I am not an admin, I am simple employee who wants to use Mingw-w64 but don't know how to install it without admin rights.

Comment: You're the one who wrote mingw-w64? The person who wrote that application is the one who can answer the question, is what I'm saying.

Comment: Ah, that developer. Okay will do, thanks for the answer.

Comment: I've rephrased the answer so that it is perhaps more clear. Please indicate this is the correct answer by marking it as such.

Answer (score 0):

if you have scoop you can try
`scoop install msys2`
it will install it, however it won't shim it if it detects you have another mingw enviroment installed.